# Why are AI Safety discussions almost always from the perspective of reinforcement learning?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, agi, ai-safety, singularity

I have been reading some articles on AI safety and they almost always speak of AI Safety from the reinforcement learning (RL) perspective, i.e. where we have some artificially intelligent agent acting in an environment so to maximise some reward.

Is there a reason why the focus is very often from this RL POV?

Thanks.

Examples:

- [2021 AI Alignment Literature Review and Charity Comparison](https://www.lesswrong.com/posts/C4tR3BEpuWviT7Sje/2021-ai-alignment-literature-review-and-charity-comparison)
- [Unsolved Problems in ML Safety](https://arxiv.org/abs/2109.13916)
- [Paperclip Maximizer](https://www.lesswrong.com/tag/paperclip-maximizer)
- [AI Alignment Research Overview by Jacob Steinhardt](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1FbTuRvC4TFWzGYerTKpBU7FJlyvjeOvVYF2uYNFSlOc/edit)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you are really asking is why don't we talk about alignment from the perspective of general deep learning?

In fact, we do talk about alignment for general AI system that's being used in production. For example, [making large language model less toxic](https://aclanthology.org/2020.findings-emnlp.301.pdf) is an active
area of research.

The reason you see a lot of references to RL in the context alignment is that one method that has been actively researched to make our AI systems aligned with our preference is through [training them via RL](https://openai.com/blog/instruction-following/). The reward function is, not surprisingly, good alignment with human preferences.